# JUnit test suite involving file reading is performing differently on Windows 10 and Fedora 23

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, windows-10, fedora-23

Suppose my entire Eclipse project is in a directory called `project` and in `project`, there is a regular non-empty, well-formatted file, `data.txt`, and a single directory `src`. In `src`, there are two directories: `code` and `test` for packages named exactly the same as the directories.

In `code`, I have the following file `A.java`

```
package code;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class A {
  private static Map<Integer, String> m = makeMap("data.txt");

  private static Map<Integer, String> makeMap(String file) {
    Map<Integer, String> m = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    try {
      int i = 0;
      Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(file));
      while (s.hasNextLine()) {
        m.put(i, s.nextLine());
      }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.exit(1);
    }
    return m;
  }

  // a bunch of public static methods that use the global static variable m
}
```

In `test`, I have `ATest.java`, which is a JUnit test file for `A.java`. It just contains several test cases that test the public static functions in `A.java`.

Also in `test`, I have another file `TestSuite.java`, which is the following

```
package test;

import org.junit.runners.Suite;
import org.junit.runners.Suite.SuiteClasses;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ ATest.class })

public final class TestSuite { }
```

If I were to run `ATest` on any machine, it will pass all the tests. If I were to run `TestSuite` on a Windows 10 machine, the tests in `ATest` will fail, but if I were run `TestSuite` on a Fedora 23 Linux machine, `TestSuite` passes all of the tests.

In particular, on Windows, the program is able to successfully make it all the way through the `try` block without throwing an exception, but the problem is that `s.hasNextLine()` returns `false` so it never reads the contents of the file. This is contrary on a Fedora, where `s.hasNextLine()` returns `true` and proceeds to do be able to perform actions on the global map. The thing that confuses me is that the `data.txt` is the same on both platforms, so why would one platform perform differently than the other?

Does anybody know why this is happening, and what I can do to make my code be platform independent?

EDITS:
`data.txt` contains Japanese characters, so it is encoded in UTF-8 if that helps

Comment: What is the encoding of the text file? This is just a suspicion. Another one is the path of the file. You may check both.

Comment: It contains Japanese characters so it's in UTF-8. Does that cause an issue? Also, can you explain what you mean by the path of the file? It's contained in project, so it should be project/data.txt if that's what you're looking for, but I don't think that's what you're asking about.

Comment: As I said it was two things that you SHOULD check if you think that the path is not the problem it leaves you the encoding and the answer from @ArchimedesTrajano already gives you a possible solution. Files opened in windows systems its not always UTF-8 most of the time they are ANSI so you should address the problem on your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the encoding of the file that you are reading.  If it is not specified, it will use the platform default which is not always UTF-8

This is done using the [`Scanner(File, String charset)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%29) constructor.